# sql group_by count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

i have a database like this:[image]

I want to count id by month like this result :

```
id    creat_time

6     2018-8
```

I tried this query:

```
"SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time),COUNT(id) FROM b_project WHERE creat_time GROUP_BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time)"
```

But I got the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP_BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time)' at line 1

How to fix it?

Comment: You're missing a condition in your `WHERE` clause...

Comment: the full sql how to write?

Comment: You probably don't need the `WHERE` clause at all, try just deleting `WHERE creat_time` from the query.

Comment: it do not work when i delet WHERE clause

Comment: Please edit the question with the new query and the output...

Comment: @Nick Please add MySQL tag

Comment: @donPablo I can't because someone has already done an edit that needs approval...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is trying to point us to the error.  But it can only tell us what line# has the problem.  Since the SELECT is all on one line, we don't get much information.  Please reformat the Select as follows, putting each item on a separate line.

Also,  GROUP_BY might probably be two separate words without any hyphen, so try that.

```
SELECT 
       Extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM create_time),
       Count(id)

FROM   b_project

GROUP  BY 
       Extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM create_time)
```

Comment: @董学强 . . . You should accept this answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is your existing query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time),COUNT(id) 
FROM b_project 
WHERE creat_time 
GROUP_BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time)
```

The where clause is incomplete, that will cause an error. You need to do something to compare the column to something: e.g.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time),COUNT(id) 
FROM b_project 
WHERE creat_time > '2018-09-01'
GROUP_BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from creat_time)
```

and, according to an image in your question the column name is create_time, so that needs correction as well, e.g.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from create_time),COUNT(id) 
FROM b_project 
WHERE create_time > '2018-09-01'
GROUP_BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from create_time)
```